# Incorrect outputs of Limit command

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, bugs

Version 12.0 produces a generic result

```
Limit[Cos[a*x], x -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]
```

> `Indeterminate`

and

```
Limit[Cos[a*x], x -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `Indeterminate`

instead of

> `ConditionalExpression[Indeterminate, a != 0]`

and

```
Limit[Cos[a*x], x -> Infinity, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> None]
```

> `Indeterminate`

instead of the returned input, though the documentation to the `Limit`
command (see Examples/Options/GenerateConditions there) says

> With `GenerateConditions->True`, even these non-generic conditions are reported

and states that with `GenerateConditions->None` the command returns unevaluated if the results depend on the value of parameters.

The following commands  produce correct results:

```
Limit[D[Cos[a/x^2], x]*x, x -> 0, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals]
```

> `Indeterminate`

```
Limit[D[Cos[a/x^2], x]*x, x -> 0, Assumptions -> a \[Element] Reals, GenerateConditions -> True]
```

> `ConditionalExpression[Indeterminate, a != 0]`

Are these bugs or I'm missing something?

Comment: Not a bug but the documentation wording could be better. As the relevant documentation example shows, only result for the condition that gives the generic case is shown. This effectively implies that the "non-generic conditions are reported". What is not given is the limit (0, in this case) for the non-generic condition.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau: Sorry,  don't understand you.

Comment: The only part of my comment that matters is the first three words.